# calendar methods

Tags: java, date

apart from the inbuilt functions, can we use any simple formulas to calculate the start day of the month given month and year as inputs??

Comment: I certainly recommend you use the in-built methods. Nowadays that would mean [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Avoid `Calendar`, it’s a poorly designed and long outdated class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - use the `Calendar` object:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2009)
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE) //0-based so that Calendar.JANUARY is 0
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
```

Then:

```
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //is Calendar.MONDAY
```

So you could easily compose a method for this:

```
/** takes a 1-based month so that Jjanuary is 1 */
public int getDayAtStart(int year, int month) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DayOfWeek dow = getFirstDayOfMonth(2021, 5);
        out.println(dow); // SATURDAY

        // As weekday number
        out.println(dow.getValue()); // 6

        // Some predefined styles
        out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)); // Saturday
        out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH)); // Sat
        out.println(dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW, Locale.ENGLISH)); // S

        // Formatting using DateTimeFormatter
        out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(dow)); // Saturday
        out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(dow)); // Sat
        out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(dow)); // S
    }

    private static DayOfWeek getFirstDayOfMonth(int year, int month) {
        return YearMonth.of(year, month)
                        .atDay(1)
                        .getDayOfWeek();
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/m1UMPP)

**Note:** If your requirement is to find the same for a specific timezone, use [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) as shown below:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DayOfWeek dow = getFirstDayOfMonth(2021, 5, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
        out.println(dow); // SATURDAY
    }

    private static DayOfWeek getFirstDayOfMonth(int year, int month, ZoneId zoneId) {
        return YearMonth.of(year, month)
                        .atDay(1)
                        .atStartOfDay(zoneId)
                        .getDayOfWeek();
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/lHmqsz)

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As ever, I'd recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). I dare say `java.util.Calendar` will work for this, but I prefer to use Joda Time for *all* date and time calculations wherever possible. The built-in APIs are horrible. Joda makes this very easy indeed. (Unless specified, `LocalDate` assumes an `ISOChronology` - I expect that's what you want, but you can specify a different one if you need to.)

```
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Test
{
    // Just for the sake of a simple test program!
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Prints 1 (Monday)
        System.out.println(getFirstDayOfMonth(2009, 6));
    }

    /** Returns 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday) */
    private static int getFirstDayOfMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        LocalDate date = new LocalDate(year, month, 1);
        return date.getDayOfWeek();
    }
}
```

Or if you just need to do this in one place, you can mash it into a single line if you want:

```
int day = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).getDayOfWeek();
```

It's hard to see how it could be much simpler than that :)

Comment: Not much point in learning Joda time now that JSR 310 is about to hit the shelves?

Comment: I'll believe it when I see it actually released - and when everyone is actually *using* Java 7. I don't expect everywhere to jump to it the instant it's shipped. Besides with the same designer I expect it'll be similar enough that time spent learning Joda Time now won't be wasted anyway.

Comment: If you look at it, it feels quite different to JODA

Comment: I bet it feels closer to Joda than it does to Date/Calendar... and anyway, in the meantime I'd *much* rather use a decent API with an appropriate separation of dates, times, instants etc than calendar. I've been doing a *lot* of date/time work over the last year, and I wouldn't go back to Date/Calendar for anything...

Answer (score 1):

construct a calendar (cal) with the given month and year, and day 1, and `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`... sorry, don't think there are any builtins just for that task